# Error using Object Streams with SSL Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I have a pair of client-server java programs that are using secure communication for object transfer (using Object input and output streams). This program is a multi-client program and for each client a separate thread is used. Here is a snippet of the code below:

```
final static private ServerSocketFactory serverFactory 
    = SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
final static private SocketFactory clientFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
serverSocket 
    = serverFactory.createServerSocket
        (port, 0, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.2"));
while(running) {
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("Client connected :: " + clientSocket);
    System.out.println("Creating client thread...");
    Client c = new Client(count++, clientSocket);
    c.T.start();
}
```

The thread which will handle the clients request:

```
Client(int id, Socket cs){
    T = new Thread(this, "Client Thread" + id);
    this.socket = cs;
    this.id = null;
    try{
        input = new ObjectInputStream(cs.getInputStream());
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
        successful = true;
    }catch(IOException ex){
        successful = false;
    }
}
```

The code for client program is very similar. When I run both the programs and send the request from the client to the server, the server will accept the request but when execution reaches the lines where the Object Streams are retrieved from the socket, I get an error:
**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common**

Can anyone help me with this? And are there better ways of using secure communication between client and server in java GUIs?

Comment: What client and server type are you using? JVM type, platform, OS,... IMHO ObjectStreams are bad for transferring (custom) data objects as you often run into incompatibilities between different platforms.

Comment: I have no idea what type it is. (first time I heard a client-server application has a **type** property). What can be the problems leading to this exception?

Comment: There are dozens of different Java VMs out there: SunJDK, OpenJDK, Android, ... and of course they all exist in different versions, supporting different SSL/TLS ciphers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an issue with using object streams as the SSLHandshakeException occurs before any data is transferred over the connection.  The exception message indicates that the issue is finding an encryption method that the server and the client agree on.  The server supports one set of ciphers, and the client supports a different set of ciphers, and there is no cipher that is in both sets.  This is assuming the exception message is accurate; sometimes it seems this exception can be a side effect of other SSL issues.

I'd suggest the next step would be to call and print out the results of the getDefaultCipherSuites() and getSupportedCipherSuites() on the client and server SSL socket factories.  If the exception is accurate, there should be no overlap between the default cipher suites, but hopefully there will be some overlap in the supported cipher suites which you can then set the SSL socket factories to enable and use.